# How to open encrypted PDF with PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, web-applications, pdf, pdf-generation

I would like to know, is it possible to open Acrobat-generated PDF's encrypted with a simple password using PHP? For example, a function similar to:

```
$data = pdf_open($file, $password);
```

I know the standard PHP libraries have functions to read, set, and write PDF files w/o password protection. I would like to know if this is possible with passwords.

I have also looked into external libraries like FPDF and mPDF, both of which I am still not quite sure if it supports reading password protected PDF's.

Any suggestions? recommendations? The PDF is always password protected and the PHP application always have access to that password.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.codediesel.com/php/encrypting-uploaded-files-in-php/

Comment: Sorry but I think you misunderstood the point. I am trying to _open_ a file that has been password protected using Adobe Acrobat